# how to add list of class inside of class (preferably with reflection if possible)

Tags: c#

I have a list of type class, and I want to add up the members inside, how do I go about to achieve this?

```
void Main()
{
    var a1 = new A(){id =2};
    var a2 = new A(){id =3, xx=1};
    var a3 = new A(){id =2, yy=2};
    var a4 = new A(){id =2, xx=4, yy=6};

    var a5 = new A(){cc = new C(){id =2, xx=1}};
    var a6 = new A(){cc = new C(){id =2}};
    var a7 = new A(){cc = new C(){id =2}};

    var b = new B();
    b.SomeMethod(new List<A>{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7});
}
```

Class C is used inside class A. Both classes are 3pty API, so I cant modify it.

```
public class A
{
      public int id {get;set;}
      public int xx {get;set;}
      public int yy {get;set;}
      public C cc {get; set;}
 } 

public class C
{
            public int id {get;set;}
            public int xx {get;set;}
            public int yy {get;set;}
}
```

Now instead of adding up single member of the class in the list of class, I need the a return of class where all the member inside of the class are added up.

```
public class B
{
    public void SomeMethod(IList<A> listOfA)
    {
        int result1 = listOfA.Sum(A => A.id);//return 9
        int result2 = listOfA.Sum(A => A.xx);//return 5
        int result3 = listOfA.Sum(A => A.yy);//return 8
        int result4 = listOfA.Where(A=>A.cc != null).Sum(A => A.cc.id);
//return 6

        //var resultAll = ???;//return new A(){id = 9, xx = 5, yy = 8, cc = new C(){id =6, xx = 1}}  
    }
}
```

Basically I need help on how to achieve result as below from above

```
//var resultAll = ???;//return new A(){id = 9, xx = 5, yy = 8, cc = new C(){id =6, xx = 1}}
```

Comment: And the problem statement and question is…? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not in a correct mindframe due to the long work hours. I have updated the question, I hope it make sense a bit more with few hours sleep to clear up my mind. Apologies again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are checking for `null` values before computing the sum. Following code should work

```
int result4 = listOfA.Where(A=>A.cc != null).Sum(A => A.cc.id); 
int result5 = listOfA.Where(A=>A.cc != null).Sum(A => A.cc.xx); 

 var resultAll = new A() {
                         id = result1,
                         xx = result2,
                         yy = result3,
                        cc = new C()
                        {
                            id = result4,
                            xx = result5
                        }
                      };
```

Comment: Thanks! that help with 1 of the 2 issue I'm facing, I've edited my question with your answer, but the other ones is still pending...

Comment: what should be the value for resultAll ?

Comment: yeah... this is what I do right now, I suppose this is the way to do it. Accepting the answer...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, check this code, might help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpConsoleApplication.Tests
{
    class OperatorsOverloadingTest
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            var list = new List<ParentObject>() { 
                new ParentObject() { IntegerValue = 1 },
                new ParentObject() { IntegerValue = 2 },
                new ParentObject() { Child = new ChildObject() { DoubleValue = 10D } },
                new ParentObject() { Child = new ChildObject() { DoubleValue = 20D } }
            };

            ParentObject pTotal = new ParentObject();

            foreach (var p in list)
                pTotal += p;

            Console.WriteLine(pTotal);
        }
    }

    public class ParentObject
    {
        public int IntegerValue { get; set; }

        public ChildObject Child { get; set; }



        public ParentObject()
        {
            Child = new ChildObject();
        }



        public static ParentObject operator +(ParentObject item1, ParentObject item2)
        {
            var parent = new ParentObject() { IntegerValue = item1.IntegerValue + item2.IntegerValue };
            parent.Child = item1.Child + item2.Child;

            return parent;
        }



        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("IntegerValue={0}, Child={1}", IntegerValue, Child);
        }
    }



    public class ChildObject
    {
        public double DoubleValue { get; set; }

        public static ChildObject operator +(ChildObject item1, ChildObject item2)
        {
            return new ChildObject() { DoubleValue = item1.DoubleValue + item2.DoubleValue };
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("DoubleValue={0}", DoubleValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it work, but what I failed to mentioned is that both the parent and child class is from another 3pty API, and I cant put a constructor there. Is it possible to provide alternative solution?